# Jekyll doesn't rebuild the site after one change

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I have Jekyll 3.1.3.

As the title, Jekyll doesn't rebuilt when I modify one file's _posts.

Initially, the output directory '_sites' is empty and I run jekyll:

```
$ jekyll build --watch --incremental
```

When Jekyll is running, I create the first page and so I add some posts, creating the following structure:

```
/ --> jekyll_path
.... category1/ 
........... index.html
........... _posts/
.................. post1.md 
.................. post2.md
.................. post3.md
.... _sites/
```

Jekyll with --watch enable initializes to populate the _sites/ directory correctly .

But......but.......

Now, I modify the content of post1.md or delete post1.md, Jekyll's output:

```
  Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2016-04-26 13:39:19 ...done in 0.357404 seconds.
```

But the HTML page in _site/category1 directory remained unchanged. Jekyll didn't overwrite the files with the changes.

Note: category1/index.html print the content of every *.md in category1/_posts

Note2: the web server is SimpleHTTPServer of python and it runs on _sites/.

Comment: Can you try same thing with `jekyll serve`

Comment: But with jekyll serve , it runs as a web server, I want that jekyll works in back-end. It has to build only , generating the html page.

Comment: Sorry I just saw the `-incremental`. I guess,  you're experimenting a Jekyll bug. You'd better [fill an issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/new).